# Is there a way play a sound with a specific frequency that is transmitted through the raspberry pi's audio jack to a speaker?

Tags: audio, audio-playback

I am trying to make it so that the code and change the frequency of the sound based on external inputs. So it should be able to update with new frequencies in real time. Preferably it would be with python so I can use GPIOzero with it.

Comment: Could this be what you're looking for? [Pi Tone Generator with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48769993/raspberry-pi-generate-and-play-tone-from-python-code-with-sox)

Comment: @jw20 Please make an answer but not only with a link (no link-only answer) so *@SnailDragon* can accept it to finish his question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this be what you're looking for?

[Pi Tone Generator with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48769993/raspberry-pi-generate-and-play-tone-from-python-code-with-sox)

Good example here of how to do it.